# Lightning Message Services (beta) - no response

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, lightning-message-service

I tried playing around with Lightning Message Services as per the release note. Created a LWC to publish message on the message channel, and a VF page to listen to it. Also the other way around. 
I am not able to receive or view any messages on either side, when I subscribe to the channel. I am simply following the example given on the release note (https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_lc_message_channel.htm). 
Has anyone done this successfully?

Comment: I'm working with this right now and have a working aura-VF example. I know you've said you're copying the code from the example, but maybe paste your code in here so we can take a look.

Comment: Peter, thx for your reply. I am able to get it working. I was mixing up the code examples from Winter 20 developer preview, Spring 20 and a few other blogs. No issues in the code given in examples.

Comment: FYI, you can answer your own question. Maybe you'll save others from the same. :-)

Comment: I have created one demo: https://newstechnologystuff.com/2020/03/22/lightning-message-service-quick-demo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get it working. I was mixing up the code examples from Winter 20 developer preview, Spring 20 and a few other blogs. No issues in the code given in examples from Salesforce. :)

Comment: Could you please explain in more details, was it due to different API versions?